# How to create a LatLngBounds around a LatLng point with a distance in meters?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to create a square (LatLngBounds) around a central point (LatLng) at X meters.

Comment: If I can create a point at X meters from my central point, i could use the 2nd constructor of LatLngBounds:
L.latLngBounds( <LatLng[]> latlngs )
[http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-l.latlngbounds][1]

But i could not find how to do that too.

  [1]: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-l.latlngbounds

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [`L.LatLng.toBounds()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlng-tobounds), e.g.

```
var center = L.latLng(40,-3);
var bounds = center.toBounds(500);
```

or

```
var bounds = L.latLng(40,-3).toBounds(500)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution demonstrates how to draw such a square:

- calculate bounds by drawing a circle at point with radius specified
  in meters
- draw a square using circle bounds

Example

```
function drawSquare(map, center, properties, sideLengthInMeters){
    var circle = L.circle(center, sideLengthInMeters/2).addTo(map);   
    var bounds = circle.getBounds();
    map.removeLayer(circle); //hide circle
    var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, properties).addTo(map);
    return rect;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var center = [59.33,18.02];

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 10);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        { maxZoom: 18 }).addTo(map);

    
L.marker(center).addTo(map);

var sideInMeters = 10000;
drawSquare(map,center,{ color: 'blue', weight: 1 }, sideInMeters);


function drawSquare(map, center, properties, sideLengthInMeters){
    var circle = L.circle(center, sideLengthInMeters/2).addTo(map);   
    var bounds = circle.getBounds();
    map.removeLayer(circle); //hide circle
    var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, properties).addTo(map);
    return rect;
}
```

```css
#map { 
    height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```